# Backgroung image height not getting reduced

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

i have a chat page in which each chat bubble contains msg, msg time,read status etc. All these are textview's which is inside a relative layout. This relative layout has a background image which is the chat bubble image. My problem is, the chat bubble height is not getting smaller when message content is less.

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/chatImageContainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/chat_others"
        android:minWidth="150dp"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/msg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="16sp" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/thumbnailView"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:max="100"
            android:minHeight="50dp"
            android:minWidth="50dp"
            android:progress="1"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What you have tried? post the xml

Comment: i have posted the xml

Comment: what is ur bubble image(chat_others) size?

Comment: its a nine patch image. Actually i am setting the background image programatically. When tha msg content is large it will automatically increase its size. but when msg content are small its size not getting reduced.

Comment: are u making imageview and progressbar visible in code?

Comment: yes. But not in all conditions.

Comment: in which condition they r visible?

Comment: when i receive picture messages

Comment: `its a nine patch image.` Post it (post both of them: left and right). `Actually i am setting the background image programatically.` For choosing left and right, OK.

Comment: Yes,for choosing left and right.

Comment: Obviously. But I asked you to post your 9 patches, in order to see where is the error. Also make sure the extension is **.9.png**, not **.png**

Comment: Sorry @Der Golem, i can't post the image, because of copyright issues.But the image is .9.png patch.

Comment: Copyright issues... on a speech bubble?! Really?! Sorry, I can't help you.

Comment: Thank you @Der Golem, Thank you for spending your precious time for me.

Comment: It seems you don't want to be helped: "Doctor! My heart aches!" "Let's see your heart." "I can't show it to you, because of my religion" "OK, die"